# Dynamically pull the correct email address from a match

Tags: php

Here's my current function,

```
 class emailer {
  function notifyHeart($post_ID)  {
    $interests = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'interests');
    $post = get_post($post_ID);

    foreach($interests as $interest) {
      if(has_tag($interest, $post)) {
        $to = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', get_current_user_id() );  
        $email = $to;
        mail($email, "An article about Heart", 'A new post has been published!');
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
add_action('publish_post', array('emailer', 'notifyHeart'));
```

So far it only works with one user, the other user isn't receiving an email when there's a tag from post that match their interest.

Ideally, I would like to retrieve an email only when a user's $interest matches a tag from a post, then the appropriate email address will be selected and sent.

Comment: Would changing, code $to = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', get_current_user_id() ); to code$to = get_usermeta( $userid, 'user_email' ); make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

Who should retrieve an email? The hook 'publish_post' is triggered when an author puiblish a post. So current user == post author.

I assume you would do that: If Buddy-A publish a post and Buddy-B is logged in at the same time, than Buddy-B should retrieve an email that Buddy-A published a post (which maybe interrest Buddy-B).

If I hit the nail and this is it what you want to do, forget it. WordPress have no centralized user management. You need a plugin ( see [List of logged in users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802525/list-of-logged-in-users-in-wordpress) ) to get a list of all users currently logged in. Call your function for every user in the list and check if a interest match a post tag.

Comment: I see, thank you, that does make sense. Is it possible to retrieve a list of all users, even those who aren't logged in? That way it may be possible to cross reference each user and match those with their interests.

Comment: Yes, with `get_users()` (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users). I would exclude the current user ( `$users = get_users( array( 'exclude' => get_current_user_id() ) );` ) to prevent sending the post author an email.